# Make a column for each count(*) in a day of the week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of people who are doing piece work. Every entry in the table has a user-ID, name, and a Date for each report they enter.

I need to make a weekly report of what these people have done per day starting with Sunday

1. How do you group by a week starting Sunday?
2. How do you make a column for each COUNT(*) per day?

---

```
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-29
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-29
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-29
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-29
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-29
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-28
t0001, Tod, 2015-6-28
b0002, Ben, 2015-6-29
b0002, Ben, 2015-6-29
b0002, Ben, 2015-6-28
```

This is what I'm looking for.

```
NAME | S | M | T | W | R | F | S | TOTAL
----------------------------------------
TOD  | 2 | 5 | - | - | - | - | - | 7
BEN  | 1 | 2 | - | - | - | - | - | 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following approach in SQL Server to pivot the data into the format you are looking for.  You may also be able to use the PIVOT operator, but I tend to prefer to write out the CASE statements since I find that syntax more clear (they have always resolved to the same query plan in all cases that I have checked).

Updated answer based on Aaron pointing out the shortcomings with DATENAME.  Thanks for pointing that out, Aaron!  We work primarily with English-based databases, but that was obviously a silly assumption to make more broadly.

```
-- Load test data
CREATE TABLE #reportDates (employeeName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, reportDate DATE NOT NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO #reportDates (employeeName, reportDate)
VALUES
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-28'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-28'),
    ('Ben', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Ben', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Ben', '2015-6-28')

-- Build the report for each employee
DECLARE @reportStartDate DATE = '2015-6-28' /* Sunday, the start date of the report */
SELECT employeeName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS R,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 5 THEN 1 END) AS F,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, reportDate) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM #reportDates
WHERE reportDate BETWEEN @reportStartDate/*Sunday, report start date*/ AND DATEADD(dd, 6, @reportStartDate)/* Saturday, report end date */
GROUP BY employeeName
```

For reference, here was the original response (that is incorrect if not using English!):

```
-- Load test data
CREATE TABLE #reportDates (employeeName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, reportDate DATE NOT NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO #reportDates (employeeName, reportDate)
VALUES
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-28'),
    ('Tod', '2015-6-28'),
    ('Ben', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Ben', '2015-6-29'),
    ('Ben', '2015-6-28')

-- Build the report for each employee
SELECT employeeName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Monday' THEN 1 END) AS M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END) AS T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN 1 END) AS W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Thursday' THEN 1 END) AS R,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Friday' THEN 1 END) AS F,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, reportDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM #reportDates
WHERE reportDate BETWEEN '2015-6-28'/*Sunday, report start date*/ AND '2015-7-4'/* Saturday, report end date */
GROUP BY employeeName
```

You could also consider using the `DATEPART` function, but be aware that it depends on how `DATEFIRST` is configured and therefore may not always return the same results across different databases or if the configuration is changed:

```
-- Compare DATENAME vs. DATEPART for day of the week
SELECT DATENAME(dw, '2015-6-29')
-- Monday
GO
SELECT DATEPART(dw,'2015-6-29')
-- 2
GO

-- Reconfigure the "first" day of the week to be Thursday
SET DATEFIRST 4
GO

-- Compare DATENAME vs. DATEPART for day of the week after setting DATEFIRST
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2015-6-29')
-- Monday, which remains consistent
GO
SELECT DATEPART(dw,'2015-6-29')
-- 5, which means that DATEPART is not guaranteed for this usage!
GO

-- Reconfigure the "first" day of the week to Sunday (the default for US English)
SET DATEFIRST 7
GO
```

Comment: FYI Datename can break similarly to datepart - try SET LANGUAGE FRENCH; for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Just shows the danger of trying to use those "day of week" date functions, and it's good to get out of my English-centric thinking.  My updated approach ends up looking a bit more similar to yours once I fixed that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way. Assuming this table and sample data:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.splunge(UserID CHAR(5), Name VARCHAR(32), Date DATE);

INSERT dbo.splunge(UserID, Name, Date) VALUES('t0001','Tod','20150629'),
  ('t0001','Tod','20150629'),('t0001','Tod','20150629'),('t0001','Tod','20150629'),
  ('t0001','Tod','20150629'),('t0001','Tod','20150628'),('t0001','Tod','20150628'),
  ('b0002','Ben','20150629'),('b0002','Ben','20150629'),('b0002','Ben','20150628');
```

Then with a variable or parameter to dictate the week you care about:

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = '20150702';

-- roll it back to Sunday
SET @dt = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19050101', @dt), '19050101');

;WITH dt(dt) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (7) dt = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1, @dt)
  FROM sys.all_objects
  ORDER BY [object_id]
),
x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    s.Name, dt.dt, 
    dd = DATEDIFF(DAY, @dt, dt.dt), 
    c = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), COUNT(*))
  FROM dt
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.splunge AS s 
  ON s.Date = dt.dt
  GROUP BY Grouping SETS((s.Name),(s.Name,dt.dt))
)
SELECT 
  Name, 
  [S] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 0 THEN c END), '-'),
  [M] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 1 THEN c END), '-'),
  [T] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 2 THEN c END), '-'),
  [W] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 3 THEN c END), '-'),
  [T] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 4 THEN c END), '-'),
  [F] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 5 THEN c END), '-'),
  [S] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE dd WHEN 6 THEN c END), '-'),
  TOTAL = MAX(CASE WHEN dt IS NULL THEN c END)
FROM x
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Name;
```

Results:

```
Name    S   M   T   W   T   F   S   TOTAL
------  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- -----
Ben     1   2   -   -   -   -   -   3
Tod     2   5   -   -   -   -   -   7
```

Another way:

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = '20150702';

-- make sure Sunday is the "beginning" of the week:
SET DATEFIRST 7;

-- roll it back to Sunday
SET @dt = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19050101', @dt), '19050101');

;WITH dt AS
(
  SELECT Name, dw = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date)
  FROM dbo.splunge
  WHERE Date >= @dt AND Date < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @dt)
),
x AS
(
  SELECT Name, dw = COALESCE(dw, 8),  
    c = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), COUNT(*))
  FROM dt 
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Name),(Name,dw))
)
SELECT Name, 
  [S] = COALESCE([1],'-'),
  [M] = COALESCE([2],'-'),
  [T] = COALESCE([3],'-'),
  [W] = COALESCE([4],'-'),
  [T] = COALESCE([5],'-'),
  [F] = COALESCE([6],'-'),
  [S] = COALESCE([7],'-'),
  TOTAL = [8]
FROM x 
PIVOT (MAX(c) FOR dw IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) AS pvt;
```

Don't forget to clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.splunge;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if is equal on SQL Server, I did this in MySQL using the `WEEKDAY` function.

Table `UserRecords`:

[image]

Query:

```
    SELECT
        user,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=6 THEN qDate END) as S,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=0 THEN qDate END) as M,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=1 THEN qDate END) as T,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=2 THEN qDate END) as W,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=3 THEN qDate END) as R,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=4 THEN qDate END) as F,
        count(case when WEEKDAY(qDate)=5 THEN qDate END) as S,
        count(id) as TOTAL
    FROM UserRecords
    WHERE qDate BETWEEN '2015-06-26' AND '2015-06-29'
    GROUP BY user
    ORDER BY user DESC;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is anything similar to WEEKDAY for sql-server?

Comment: Here:

Use datename

`select datename(dw,getdate()) --Friday`

`select datepart(dw,getdate()) --6`

Edit weekdays in query.